# CakePHP mkdir permision denied

Tags: apache, cakephp, debian-based

I've just started trying to put a small web server on a Raspberry Pi running Rasbian Jessie. I've been following the steps to run CakePHP from this article: http://tecadmin.net/setup-cakephp-3-on-linux/

The issue comes when I hit step 3. I typed the command to make an app and it throws the ErrorException mkdir:Permission denied

From searching on here, this has something to do with my group permissions but that setting them to 0777 is dangerous. Can anyone explain what needs permission and how I would do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your raspian user seems to have not the permissions.
 using sudo should work. 
 sudo composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app MyApp
 Or for the changing maually the permissions after installation 
 sudo chown -R apache:apache MyApp
 sudo chmod -R 755 MyApp

Comment: I found cakePHP doesn't like it when you sudo anything. Not sure why, and I'll do some reading later about. I found adding this to a group and changing the groups permissions. Thank you!